# Python Matplotlib spy(sparse matrix) is very different from Matlab spy(sparse matrix)

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a sparse matrix `(10000 x 10000)` elements. I've tried using the `spy()` function from both matplotlib and MATLAB. I see a big difference in the output, but I can't figure out why.

Why is there such a big difference?

### Matlab:

[image]

### matplotlib:

[image]

For the matplotlib version, I'm using an iPython notebook with Python 2.7

Code for import:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from MCL import MCL
from SpectralClusterizer import SpectralClusterizer

pl.xkcd()
%matplotlib inline
pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15.0, 12.0) # set default size of plots

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Code for plotting:

```
pl.spy(A[perm][:, perm], markersize = 1, precision = 0)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Try playing with different `markersize`s in matlab. I guess it's just the representation. Try testing it on smaller matrices to get better idea.

Comment: What's up with the wobbly axis lines in the matplotlib version? Are you using the [XKCD style](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#xkcd-style-sketch-plotting) or something?

Comment: @ali_m idk, plots are always wobbly in ipython notebooks, I guess it default there

Comment: @Fortyq No, that's not normal behavior for matplotlib. Could you show us your plotting code please?

Comment: Why on Earth are you turning on `xkcd` mode?

Comment: Well, you clearly *are* using the XKCD style. Try commenting out `pl.xkcd()` and making the marker size a bit bigger

Comment: Yes xkcd is the one to blame. Out TA distributes starter code in ipython notebooks, I didnt know it may cause such problems. I even coded assignment in matlab ot figure out whats wrong with my code. Thank you guys!